# Characters detection on a non-uniform background image

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to do characters detection, have to draw a box around them, then crop and then feed to a neural network for recognition. Everything is working but before I was using sets of characters on a single color background image and segmentation was easily done.

However with real photos I have different lighting conditions and really struggle to find the contours.
After applying some adaptive thresholding I managed to get the folowing results, but starting from that I really can't figure how to properly proceed and detect each character. I can detect half of the characters easily, but not all of them. Probably because they are surrounded by lots of small irrelevant contours.
I have a feeling there is one step left but I can't figure which one.
Find Countours is capable of finding only about half of the characters.

For now, in short, im doing:

```
im_gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
im_gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(im_gray, (5, 5), 0)
_, th1 = cv2.threshold(im_gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
cim, ctrs, hier = cv2.findContours(th1.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

and

```
th2 = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(im_gray,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY,11,2)
```

Images below - original image and some variations of intermediate results.
Original picture:

[image: Original pic]

After some thresholding:

[image: After some thresholding]

After some thresholding:

[image: After some thresholding]

Inverse thresholding:

[image: Inverse thresholding]

So the question is - what is the step/steps after to segment the characters?

Comment: Have you tried reducing the noise? [Tutorial](https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.1/d5/d69/tutorial_py_non_local_means.html), [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Image_noise_reduction_techniques). Wiki has some scary names in there so try to google specific techniques in opencv to see the results (ex. [dilation, erosion](https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d9/d61/tutorial_py_morphological_ops.html) etc.)

Comment: Thank you! I actually haven't tried this. Yeah, scary names are not that scary :)

Answer (score 2):

You can perform **difference of gaussians**. The idea is to blur the image with two different kernels and subtract their respective results:

**Code:**

```
im = cv2.imread(img, 0)

#--- it is better to take bigger kernel sizes to remove smaller edges ---
kernel1 = 15
kernel2 = 31

blur1 = cv2.GaussianBlur(im,(kernel1, kernel1), 0) 
blur2 = cv2.GaussianBlur(im,(kernel2, kernel2), 0) 

cv2.imshow('Difference of Gaussians',blur2 - blur1)
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Great, thank you! That actually gave better results than all my struggles

Comment: @Alex try varying the sizes of the kernels and see different results.